# How save content of *occur* buffer?

Tags: occur

windows 10, emacs 26.1

1. M-x occur
2. Some text to find
3. Result show in *Occur* buffer.

Nice.
How I can save content of this buffer in the file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `write-file` (`C-x C-w`), then specify a filename.

> C-x C-w runs the command write-file (found in global-map), which is an
>   interactive compiled Lisp function in ‘files.el’.

Note however this does not preserve the metadata of the buffer : if you save the buffer to a file, kill the buffer and re-open the file you just saved, you only get the text, no hyperlinks.

Comment: Another way is (in *Occur* buffer): 1. Press "e", 2. "C-x C-s" to save to the file. As result it save content an metadata (e.g. hyperlinks)

Comment: @Alexei what do you mean you save with hyperlinks? In what format are you saving it? I get the same result in both cases.

Comment: @andrej After save in file I can click on hyperlinks and it's work.

Comment: @Alexei: Please consider posting your comment as another answer.